# Rails Image assets in AngularJS Directive and template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-sync

I have Rails 4 Application with AngularJS using these gems:

- gem 'angularjs-rails'
- gem 'angular-rails-templates'
- gem 'asset_sync'

It works great with a template like this:

```
    <img ng-controller='LikePostController'  
       ng-dblclick='like(post);' 
       ng-src='{{post.photo.standard}}' 
       class='lazy post_photo pt_animate_heart'
       id='post_{{post.id}}_image'
     />
```

The Image render correctly. However in  my other js

```
petto.directive('ptAnimateHeart', ['Helper', function(Helper){
    linkFunc = function(scope, element, attributes) {
      $heartIcon = $("#heart_icon");

      if($heartIcon.length == 0) {
        $heartIcon = $("<img id='heart_icon' src='/assets/feed.icon.heart.png' alt='Like' /> ");
        $(document.body).append($heartIcon);
      }

      element.on('dblclick', function(event){
        $animateObj = $(this);
        Helper.animateHeart($animateObj);
      });
    }
    return { 
      restrict: 'C',
      link: linkFunc
    }

  }])
```

I got 'assets/feed.icon.heart.png' was not found error from the browser console. I have feed.icon.heart.png located under app/assets/feed.icon.heart.png.

ps: Forget to mention I use assets sync gem to host assets in amazon s3. the image worked well in development but not in production.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hardcoded asset links only work in development because in production the assets get precompiled. Which means, amongst other things, the filename changes from:

`my_image.png`

into something like this (it adds and unique md5-hash):

`"my_image-231a680f23887d9dd70710ea5efd3c62.png"`

**Try this:**

Change the javascript file extension to: `yourjsfile.js.erb`

And the link to:

`$heartIcon = $("<img id='heart_icon' src='<%= image-url("feed.icon.heart.png") %>' alt='Like' /> ");`

For better understanding [The Asset Pipeline — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://www.google.com.kh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html&ei=AvuLU7OgEsvj8AWDyYHIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEcRFwFyWFL3DaXK1bBI-w0Cah8fg&sig2=gUWqyzestC8nGOzzmXzKWw&bvm=bv.67720277,d.dGc)

Comment: How would you do this inside of a loop? image_url doesn't work inside of javascript interpolation.

Comment: You may use the gon gem: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: It helped me. The only thing to mention: I need to use `image_url` but not `imge-url`, I am using Rails 4.2.6

Answer (score 3):

You can define the following method somewhere in your helpers, e.g. in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```rb
def list_image_assets(dir_name)
  path = File.expand_path("../../../app/assets/images/#{dir_name}", __FILE__)
  full_paths = Dir.glob "#{path}/**.*"
  assets_map = {}
  full_paths.each do |p|
    original_name = File.basename p
    asset_path    = asset_path p[p.index("#{dir_name}")..-1]
    assets_map[original_name] = asset_path
  end
  assets_map.to_json
end
```

One can modify the method to work with any assets you wish, not just the ones located in subdirs of `app/assets/images` as in this example. The method will return a map with all the original asset names as keys and their 'compiled' names as values.

The map returned can be passed to any angular controller via `ng-init` (not generally recommended, but appropriate in this case):

```html
<div ng-controller="NoController" ng-init="assets='<%=list_image_assets "images_dir_name"%>'"></div>
```

To make the assets really usable in angular, define a new `$scope` valiable in the controller:

```js
$scope.$watch('assets', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    $scope.assets = JSON.parse(value);
  }
});
```

Having this in the `$scope`, it's possible to use assets names as usual, in e.g. `ng-src` directives, and this won't brake after the precompile process.

```html
<img ng-src={{::assets['my_image.png']}}/>
```

Comment: I like this solution, this is the only one without using `.erb` and not putting images straight into the `public` directory. But it still seems too much of a pain

Comment: Good solution in that A) It forces you to understand a bit about the underlying asset compilation process and B) You can use a variant of this if you just need to pass in a small set of assets.  Using the 'gon' gem will probably make sense at some point when you find yourself doing this all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$location){
$rootScope.auth_url = "http://localhost:3000"   
$rootScope.image_url = $rootScope.auth_url + "/uploads/user/image/"
});
```

In controller inject `dependency` for `$rootScope`
and in views

```
<img ng-src="{{user.image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Note: It's working great in Rails API and it assumes that you've user object available so that it could specify the correct image in the `/uploads/image/` directory